# AngularJS 1.2.0: Lazy load controllers and templates

Tags: javascript, angularjs, requirejs, angularjs-routing

I am newbie to AngularJS. I am using the following code to achieve the lazy load dependency.

https://github.com/matys84pl/angularjs-requirejs-lazy-controllers/

This was working great with 1.0.7, but the defer promise fails to load the temaplate in 1.2.0 version.

in `js/lib/utils/route-config.js`

```
routeDefinition.template = function () {
            /*
             *  Here is the problem, 'html' is undefined on page load. 
             *  But if we click the menu navigation, the 'html' is getting loaded. 
             *  I am not sure how to achieve promise for loading template in RequireJS.
             */
            return html;
        };
        routeDefinition.controller = controllerName;


routeDefinition.resolve = {
        delay:function ($q, $rootScope) {
            defer = $q.defer();
            if (!html) {
                var dependencies = [controllerName, "text!" + templateUrl];
                if (directives) {
                    dependencies = dependencies.concat(directives);
                }
                require(dependencies, function () {
                    var controller = arguments[0],
                        template = arguments[1];

                    for (var i = 2; i < arguments.length; i++) {
                        lazyDirectives.register(arguments[i]);
                    }

                    $controllerProvider.register(controllerName, controller);
                    html = template;
                    defer.resolve();
                    $rootScope.$apply()
                })

            } else {
                defer.resolve();
            }
            return defer.promise;
        }
```

I have changed the code with the below one i.e. instead of using `template`, I have changed it to `templateUrl` and it works perfect. Since I am implementing it in salesforce.com and visualforce pages doesn't support html extension, I do not want to use `templateUrl`.

```
routeDefinition.templateUrl = 'js/'+templateUrl;
        routeDefinition.controller = controllerName;
        routeDefinition.resolve = {
            delay:function ($q, $rootScope, $http) {
                defer = $q.defer();
                if (!html) {
                    //var dependencies = ["lib/text!" + templateUrl, controllerName];
                    var dependencies = [controllerName];
                    if (routeDependends) {
                        dependencies = dependencies.concat(routeDependends.directives);
                        dependencies = dependencies.concat(routeDependends.services);
                        dependencies = dependencies.concat(routeDependends.filters);
                    }

                    require(dependencies, function () {
                        var controller = arguments[0], 
                        //template = arguments[0],
                        incCnt = 1, 
                        directiveCnt = (routeDependends.directives.length+incCnt),
                        serviceCnt = (routeDependends.directives.length+routeDependends.services.length+incCnt),
                        filterCnt = (routeDependends.directives.length+routeDependends.services.length+routeDependends.filters.length+incCnt);

                        $controllerProvider.register(controllerName, controller);

                        if(routeDependends.directives.length > 0)
                            for (var i = incCnt; i < directiveCnt; i++) { onDemandDependencies.registerDirectives(arguments[i]); }
                        if(routeDependends.services.length > 0)
                            for (var i = directiveCnt; i < serviceCnt; i++) { onDemandDependencies.registerServices(arguments[i]); }
                        if(routeDependends.filters.length > 0)
                            for (var i = serviceCnt; i < filterCnt; i++) { onDemandDependencies.registerFilters(arguments[i]); }

                        //html = template;
                        defer.resolve();
                        $rootScope.$apply()
                    });
                } else {
                    defer.resolve();
                }
                return defer.promise;
            }
        }
        console.log(routeDefinition);
        return routeDefinition;
```

Any help appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there an error in the dev console of your browser?

Comment: @jpmorin Nope, its clean. But when I console the 'html', it says undefined on page load whereas while navigating the page, it returns proper html.

Comment: I came here following your comment on github. I was in the same problem and I solved with [this approach](http://ify.io/lazy-loading-in-angularjs/). Hope this can help.

Answer (score 3):

It is not clear how your `html` is being loaded but if the issue is related to "visualforce pages doesn't support html extension", you can implement template using `<script>` tag in a existing html file as:

```
<script id="views/view1.html" type="text/ng-template">
    <h1>View1</h1>
    <div>View Message: {{message}}</div>
    <a href="#/home">Home</a>
</script>
```

Angular documentation for `ng-template`:
http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:script

Here is a plunker where template is coded in `index.html`:
http://plnkr.co/edit/TaTl5rtpxuq67roDcOss?p=preview

Plunker above uses `angularAMD` to simplify the use of RequireJS.  More info at:
http://marcoslin.github.io/angularAMD/

Comment: Thanks for the response, I have seen this in few blogs. In routeProvider $routeProvider.when(path, {templateUrl: 'path', controller: 'path'}), we can use only `template` or `templateUrl`.

Comment: @aravindtrue what I am trying to say is for you to use `templateUrl` in $routeProvider.when as you normally would and set the 'path' to the 'id' of the `<script>` tag you created.  Angular will be able to pick up the template the the `<script>` tag.  This is documented in the angular's website in the link I provided.